# How can I delete a saved game?

Tags: hacknet

I want to wipe my saved game so that I can start over without having to use a different username. There doesn't seem to be an in-game option. Which files do I need to manually modify/nuke?

Comment: Isn't New Session enough?

Comment: @MadMrCrazy If you start a new game without deleting the old, you are forced to choose a different username. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: ok that explains things.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your steam folder and follow this: `Steam/userdata/<your account number>/365450/remote`

The save file should be present in there.